# Assign formula to cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA has been giving me an error `1004` for this code:

```
Sub UpdateCellsFormula()
Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set FormulaCellsRange = Range("J17", "J95")
i = 17

For Each r In FormulaCellsRange.Cells
    r.Formula = Replace("=D17*L21+E17*M21+F17*O21+G17*N21+H17*P21+I17*Q21)/(1+0,85+0,6+0,4+0,37)", "17", i)
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone have a look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formulas assigned with `.Formula` must be in En-US locale. The decimal dot in numbers must therefore be `.`, not `,` (`1+0.85+0.6+0.4+0.37`).

Also you have a missing opening parenthesis in the beginning, right after `=`.

You also might want to learn about absolute references in Excel. That way you can copy the same formula into all cells in `FormulaCellsRange` without replacing anything:

```
Sub UpdateCellsFormula()
  ActiveSheet.Range("J17", "J95").Formula = "=(D17*$L$21+E17*$M$21+F17*$O$21+G17*$N$21+H17*$P$21+I17*$Q$21)/(1+0.85+0.6+0.4+0.37)"
End Sub
```